# VBS script issue loading a IE frame without address bar

Tags: vbscript

I've got a very strange issue.

I'm trying to open a URL through Citrix called through a VBS script.

Here is the code:

```
Set oIE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
oIE.ToolBar=0
oIE.Navigate("https://example.com/sites/example/SitePages/Home.aspx")
oIE.Height=800
oIE.Width=1500
oIE.Left=0
oIE.Top=0
Do While (oIE.Busy)
Loop
oIE.Visible=1
```

This loads fine for most users but on two specific users the script fails to work and just displays the command prompt. At that point no other user can load the script until that user either closes the command prompt or waits for it to time out.
I'm calling the script using the following:

```
c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe \\servername\share\script.vbs
```

I tried copying the user accounts so they have the same permissions but it loads fine on the test account.

I'm trying to achieve a URL 'published application' which loads an IE frame with address bar. If there's a better solution than the above code please let me know.

I have seen an error once which said it failed to call InternetExplorer.application

Hope this helps.

Kind Regards,

Scott

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the issue :)

Turned out that the Internet explorer browsers for each user needed resetting to defaults, this sorted the issue for both users.

Hope this information helps someoene.

Scott